# how can i write a parallel algorithm for test on cluster computing?

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I'm going to create a cluster computer. i'll challenge this new super computer with a parallel algorithm. How can do it? What IDE? what language and what algorithm?

i have 4 laptops with windows server 2012 x64. one of them are very strong and others are normal.
i have HPC Pack 2012 R2 on head computer for connecting them.
language is not important to me, but java and c# are better for me.

Comment: I think your problem description is _way_ to broad for one single post on stackoverflow, I see at least some part of your question going to http://www.serverfault.com as well. We dont even know what kind of computers you are gonna do this on. Any? x86? What OS? Can everything be run in a JVM? What programming languages do you have experience in? The IDE is probably the least of your concern. On a general level, please have a look at for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP. Also, as a general comment, I would first focus on the algorithm you will use to achieve this.

Comment: If the comments I gave above are satisfying I can give it as a proper answer and we can close this, yea?

Comment: thank a lot for your answer. you are right. i added details to question. is there anything that we should add?